# In Cypress, how do I check if a button has an attribute or not?

Tags: if-statement, cypress

I want to put an if condition if an attribute exist on a button or else do some other things. How can I do it in Cypress?
I have done this till now but not working...
'''

```
if(cy.get('button[type="button"]').should('have.attr','disabled')==true){
       doTaskA() 
   }else{
        doTaskB()
    }
```

''' 
This fails the whole test and not just the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind:

Maybe checkout the Cypress guide on conditional testing. They have a bit about element existence. You might be able to do something similar : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-existence

Or maybe, perform the condition check manually using jquery:

```js
let $el = Cypress.$("myselector");
if ($el.attr("myattr") === "myvalue") {
    do.A();
} else {
    do.B();
}
```